# "Does not conform to protocol" error when extending different class

Tags: swift, protocols, protocol-extension

I'm attempting to test my own class by injecting objects that adapt the `URLSession` and `URLSessionDataTask` protocols. I'm extending `NSURLSession` and `NSURLSessionDataTask` to adopt those protocols so that I can use the existing objects normally, but use test objects in unit tests.

I have the following code, with the error commented:

```
typealias SessionHandler = (NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void

protocol URLSession {

  func dataTaskWithURL(url: NSURL, completionHandler: SessionHandler) -> URLSessionDataTask

}

protocol URLSessionDataTask {

}

// Type 'NSURLSession' does not conform to protocol 'URLSession'
extension NSURLSession : URLSession {}
extension NSURLSessionDataTask : URLSessionDataTask {}
```

I understand the error, my protocol doesn't exactly match the method as implimented by `NSURLSession`. How do I fix this?

Comment: No, your 'NSUrlSession' doesn't conform to your custom protocol, since you have to implement the method you defined in the protocol.

Comment: My protocol specifies one function, which returns a `URLSessionDataTask`. `NSURLSession` has the same function, except it returns a `NSURLSessionDataTask`, which adopts `URLSessionDataTask`, so I would expect this to work.

Comment: It sounds logical, however, I think if you have this signature, you doesn't allowed to return sublcasses but the exact type.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was creating a protocol extension that creates the necessary method that `NSURLSession` requires.

```
extension NSURLSession : URLSession {
  func dataTaskWithURL(url: NSURL, completionHandler: SessionHandler) -> URLSessionDataTask {
    return dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: completionHandler) as NSURLSessionDataTask
  }
}
```